# simpler Powershell OR condition syntax

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements

Is there a simpler way to specify an `-or` condition? For example, `if ($returnValue -eq 0 -or $returnValue -eq 5)`. I would rather write something like `if ($returnValue -eq 0 -or 5)` to test two possible values of $returnValue. Of course that's doing something else. 
Ok, just thought of coercing the value into a character type using a regular expression:
`if ($returnValue -match '0|5')`
So, now that I've answered my question, any other ideas?

Comment: Simpler or more obtuse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `-contains` or `-in` where appropriate:

```
if ((0,5) -contains $returnValue)
```

or

```
if ($returnValue -in (0,5))
```

`-in` was added in PowerShell v3.

I highly discourage the regex "solution" because it can have unintended side effects and reduces clarity. For example `51 -match '0|5'` is `$true`.

Consider just formatting your `if` statement on multiple lines:

```
if (
    $returnValue -eq 0 -or
    $returnValue -eq 5
)
```

Though I still like `-contains` and `-in` for what you're trying to achieve.

```
$validVals = @(
    0,
    5,
    17
)

if ($validVals -contains $returnVal) {
    # ...
}

if ($returnVal -in $validVals) {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: I agree about the regex solution not being good for this. Thanks.